# Python Concatenation and Sort 3 Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, concatenation

I am doing concat on three dataframes, doing code like this:

```
df_bigram = pd.concat([bigramFreqTable, skipgram, df2],axis=1)
df_bigram
```

And the output of df_bigram is

```
                      bigramf   freq           Skipgram   Freq                         bigram          PMI
0  (Asam, deoksiribonukleat,)      1      (unting, DNA)    22                        (12, Å.)    11.487338
1 (deoksiribonukleat,, lebih)      1      (DNA, unting)    22                        (22, Å,)    11.487338
2            (lebih, dikenal)      1        (DNA, yang)    20                     (220, juta)    11.487338
3           (dikenal, dengan)      2        (yang, DNA)    20                 (34, ÅngströmÅ)    11.487338
4         (dengan, singkatan)      1       (DNA, dalam)    13                (A-DNA,, B-DNA,)    11.487338
5            (singkatan, DNA)      1       (dalam, DNA)    13   (Akibatnya,, protein-protein)    11.487338
6                    (DNA, ,)      2   (pasangan, basa)    11                (Alec, Jeffreys)    11.487338
7                 (,, adalah)      1   (basa, pasangan)    11        (Alfred, HersheyHershey)    11.487338
8           (adalah, sejenis)      1    (terdiri, dari)    10      (Asam, deoksiribonukleat,)    11.487338
9       (sejenis, biomolekul)      1    (dari, terdiri)    10            (Bacillus, subtilis)    11.487338
10         (biomolekul, yang)      1        (pada, DNA)    10            (Banyak, yurisdiksi)    11.487338
...            ...                ...          ...         ...               ...                  ...
```

The problem is I want to sort 'freq' by descending value. I just confused why the other column name like 'Freq' and 'PMI', they have been sorted by descending value, meanwhile 'freq' haven't been. So, I am coding this for sorting:

```
x = df_bigram.sort_values(by='freq', ascending=False)
x
```

And the output be like this:

```
                bigramf   freq             Skipgram   Freq                      bigram          PMI
72        (unting, DNA)    17    (hidrogen, ikatan)     5     (ditranskripsikan., Para)    11.487338
212         (DNA, yang)    15          (satu, pada)     3           (Temperatur, lebur)    10.487338
136    (pasangan, basa)    10          (dalam, ===)     4              (myeloid, akut.)    11.487338
83      (yang, disebut)     9      (rantai, Proses)     5             (gen., Sedangkan)    11.487338
432  (disebut, sebagai)     9     (unting, disebut)     2           (sama., Karenanya,)     9.902375
58      (terdiri, dari)     9       (DNA, memiliki)     6             (darah,, sperma,)    11.487338
525          (Hal, ini)     8       (disebut, satu)     2          (resisten, terhadap)     9.487338
888     (heliks, ganda)     7    (tergulung, lebih)     2         (banyak, kemungkinan)     7.902375
657       (rantai, DNA)     7      (Diplonema, dan)     2                (sebuah, cara)     8.902375
...          ...           ...            ...          ...                 ...                ...
```

while actually I want to sort all of the column name like 'freq', 'Freq', 'PMI' by descending value. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is if sorting in final joined column is not possible sorting only pairs `bigram`s columns and `freq`, possible solution is sorting first and mainly create default index by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df1 = bigramFreqTable.sort_values(by='freq', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = skipgram.sort_values(by='Freq', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
df3 = df2.sort_values(by='PMI', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

df_bigram = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be corrected by reindexing with the original dataframe columns as follows:

> df_bigram = df_bigram.reindex_axis(bigramFreqTable.columns, axis=1)

If you want to sort by single column then what you have implemented above is correct. But if you want to sort by multiple columns then you may try:

> x = df_bigram.sort_values(by=['freq','Freq','PMI'], ascending=False)
>
> x

Note:- when sorting by multiple columns, pandas sort_value() uses the first variable first and second variable next.